# Print "pandas.io.formats.style.Styler object" content

Tags: python, pandas

I am using "display" function in IPython library but do see the full content. Kindly guide.

```
    from sklearn import datasets
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display
importdata = datasets.load_diabetes()
rawdata = pd.DataFrame(data=importdata.data, columns=importdata.feature_names)


from pyorange.regression import *
#intialize the setup
reg1 = setup(data = rawdata,
target = 'bmi',
train_size = 0.8
)


d=compare_models()
display(d)
```

Thanks
Chokx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify **Pandas parameters**. If it is a problem with the **rows** (you need to add this code after the import statement of Pandas and before the rest of the code):

```py
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
```

If it is a problem with the **columns** :

```py
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
```

Comment: After increasing the row and column limits to max still not showing the output.

"<pandas.io.formats.style.Styler object at 0x7fd97635ccd0>"

Comment: Can you show what is the output ?